# Find function works only the first time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro in excel that is designed to modify data based upon the values in a certain cell.

The cell is filled by a dropdown box and is a list of comma separated values such as `2,3,4` or `3,1,9`.

When my macro runs it extracts the values and loops through each one:

```
LArray = Split(Range("B6").Value, ",")

For count = 0 To UBound(LArray)

    ' the current item we are looking for
    WHAT_TO_FIND = LArray(count)

    ' ... do something

Next
```

Inside of this the loop I search for the WHAT_TO_FIND value and make modifications to the row it is one.

This code was tested and all worked fine on a single value. Moreover, if the first value in the cell is found it all the code works correctly. However, subsequently the loop never finds anything.

For example: if the cell B6 contains `2,3,7` (and both 2 and 7 exist) only 2 will actually be found. After that 3 will say return not found and 7 will return not found. In fact if cell B6 contains `3,2,7` then 3 will return not found and 2 will return not fond and 7 will return not found.

I find it quite strange the find function only works if it is the first time and have little idea of what is causing this.

See full function below:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Dim WHAT_TO_FIND As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim Percentile As Double
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Dim count As Integer
    Dim LArray() As String

    LArray = Split(Range("B6").Value, ",")


    Percentile = Range("C6").Value

    ' for each part of the list in B6
    ' we will be applying our percentile function
    For count = 0 To UBound(LArray)

        ' the current item we are looking for
        WHAT_TO_FIND = LArray(count)

        ' search in our Decile table (in our Data sheet) A2 to A11
        With Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A11")

            ' set our FoundCell as the first found item

            Set FoundCell = .Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)

            ' if there exists any
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then

                ' store where we started so we don;t do it twice
                firstAddress = FoundCell.Address
                Do

                    Worksheets("Data").Range("J" & FoundCell.Row).Value = Percentile

                    ' and move to the next
                    Set FoundCell = .FindNext(FoundCell)

                Loop While FoundCell.Address <> firstAddress

            End If

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? You have a `Dim` inside of your loop which may cause issues. Try moving that to before you start your loop.

Comment: No I am not getting an error, `FoundCell is Nothing` always after the first loop, and I tried with the Dim outside the loop originally and that didn't work either.

Comment: @braX - Potentially the problem could be in the data splitting itself? When I re-arrange the order of the array before I run the loop it makes no difference to the success of the find method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple macro to loop through a range and check if each cells' value is in the array; if a match is found, then offset from the current cell and paste the value from the specific cell you want.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, arr() As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    arr = Split(ws.Range("B6").Value, ",")

        For Each cel In ws.Range("A2:A11")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If cel.Value = arr(i) Then
                    cel.Offset(, 9).Value = ws.Range("C6").Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next cel
```